# PHP FPM cycles causing huge RAM consumption

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, memory-usage

A couple of ubuntu servers, using php8.0 / php8.1, with NGINX as a webserver, causing the problem, that my memory is filling up - based on the incoming traffic (req/s), so i have to restart the fpm process every 30 minutes, because otherwise the FPM is getting really slow and the incoming requests are starting to queue up.

As i have a couple of servers, i tried different settings for the PM on all of them, to check, if the problem may not occur. So i tried the PM with static/dynamic/ondemand > and after about an hour, all of them were really slow. I also tried to have them with a max_request, to let them auto-cycle instead of let them live forever - without any success.

There are no segfaults, i am using apcu and opcache as an extension, tried to turn off the apcu, but the RAM is stacking either way - until the FPM is getting slow. Something catched my eye, when i saw, that each fpm restart causes lots of minor page faults (300k), and in the usual runtime it is up to 40-80k > and when it reaches 100k, it is starting to get slow.

Also, the shared memory is stacking, even without the apcu, so i think that each usual cycle (not the fpm restart) is causing trouble with the shared memory. I also can not see any errors about trying to allocate too much ram, or exceeding the ram in any way.

Glad for any ideas that i could check.

Edit: If i can provide any further information, feel free to let me know

Edit 2: Installed ps_mem, saw that only the SHARED memory is increasing over time, not the declared / defined one for the process child itself.

Edit 3: One of the current setups are basically this:

```
listen = /run/php/php8.1-main-fpm.sock
;listen.backlog = 8000 
listen.backlog = -1
listen.owner = www
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660

user = www
group = www

slowlog = /var/log/slow-php8.1-fpm.log
request_slowlog_timeout = 2s

pm = static
pm.max_children = 700
pm.max_requests = 0
request_terminate_timeout = 7s
pm.status_path = /status
```

I also tried to figure this out via ps_mem. Straight up after the restart, this is the output:

```
$ ps_mem  | grep php
2.2 GiB + 112.2 MiB =   2.3 GiB php-fpm8.1 (903)
```

And after two minutes in:

```
$ ps_mem  | grep php
2.3 GiB + 164.4 MiB =   2.4 GiB php-fpm8.1 (903)
```

After fifteen minutes:

```
$ ps_mem  | grep php
2.5 GiB + 272.6 MiB =   2.8 GiB php-fpm8.1 (903)
```

The server got 64 CPUs, and about 128 GB Ram.

**Edit 3:
Just had a nice discover, that is affecting the current problem - Executing this command every minute helps the problem**

```
sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

This is a temporary solution - wanna discover the roots of the problem.

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error log? When did this start - what changed? PHP is fairly memory hungry, but shouldn't need to be restarted every 30 minutes.

Comment: I certainly did, but the error log itself is empty. And the fpm log just shows, that Child X has been exited and a new one started. Somehow this has been like that forever, only the traffic increased by factor 30, because lots of new users using the site right now.

Comment: Can you show some type of process list or `htop` screenshot? I'm curious if it's few FPM processes consuming much memory, or many FPM processes consuming *some* memory.

Comment: Sure thing, added some stuff to it

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your specific app, a single page request may require a PHP-FPM worker with roughly 80MB minimum RAM alone.

Multiple that by your configured `pm.max_children = 700`, and you'll get the idea that with many requests coming in and making all workers busy, you get *at least* 56GB used. That's a scenario when your app is very lite. It can be easily 100MB or 120MB per request, etc.

This `pm.max_requests = 0` just makes it worse. There are always memory leaks and bugs in PHP worker processes. You *must* set this to something so that workers are recycled. Otherwise, the workers will just grow indefinitely in RAM, until you restart PHP-FPM and clear our the traffic. Set it to `1000` or `10000` (after that many requests, worker is recycled), but never to `0`.

And finally, do not do `request_slowlog_timeout = 2s`. Slow logging is not for production. (temporary it's ok though).

Comment: Nice answer. I wonder how much RAM the server has. Maybe it's going into virtual memory.

Comment: I had them on 1000 max request before, without any success. The cycle works as intended, but somewhat with the cycle, the memory usage looks the very same. Of course it makes a difference via settings, to not let them live forever, but as said - doesn't work really

Comment: And @Tim, the server has 128GB Ram, so we should be good for some time

Comment: 700 children processes * (say) 128MB per child = 90GB RAM. If you're also running database, web server, etc on the server you could be pushing it. Shared memory may reduce that number. I'd suggest you look at caching - web (anonymous users), PHP (page, object), database, etc.

Comment: We are using APCU + Opcache, which helps a lot - otherwise the I/O would explode. Stuff like redis / database is on a different server. This is plain nginx / php.